Is `mv` in adb shell limited in moving a directory?
I enter a shell on Android by
sudo adb shell

Now I want to move a directory (of files) in Android into another, but why does it fail
$ mv english/ ../mydata/                                                                                                                             
mv: bad 'english/': Directory not empty

It says the source directory is not empty.
This problem seems to happen regardless of whether either or both of the source and destination is in the internal memory of a phone or a SD card connected to the phone.
It also seems that the existence of / after a directory name makes difference. When it is specified, the files in the directory are moved; when not, the directory is moved.
Is it because the shell doesn't support such moving? What can its mv do only? What can I do if I want to move a directory of files?
$ echo $SHELL                                                                                                                                                          
/system/bin/sh

